# Neural network with linear activation function and feed forward from input layer to a single output layer

Tags: qbasic

Enter code here`as crappy a programmer i am, with slight dyslexia, i 
 need every thing code based witten in such a stupid way that even child 
 can understand it. I try to understand how to get input layer into 
 output layer using feed forward but the tutorials online require to much 
 education. My understanding of math is limited. I'm trying to make a 
 simple neural net with one input layer and one output layer. I 
 understand explanations in sentences better than code.

```
for i = 1 to 2
    input1(i) = input1(i) * weight1(i)
    input1(i) = input2(i) * weight2(i)
next i
for i = 1 to 2
    sum(i) = input1 + input2
next i
for i = 1 to 2
    if sum(i) > 0 then fire.
next i
end
```

Comment: Since **input1** and **input2** are not declared then the **sum(i)** will always be zero.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> for i = 1 to 2
>     input1(i) = input1(i) * weight1(i)
>     input1(i) = input2(i) * weight2(i)
> next i
> ```

The 1st assignment is redundant since both assignments store in the same variable (array element `input1(i)`).
Is this a typo? Maybe the 2nd assignment should read `input2(i) = ...` !

> ```
> for i = 1 to 2
>     sum(i) = input1 + input2
> next i
> ```

Both `sum(1)` and `sum(2)` will hold the same value because the righthandside expression stays the same throughout the loop.

> ```
> for i = 1 to 2
>     if sum(i) > 0 then fire.
> next i
> ```

Because both `sum(1)` and `sum(2)` hold the same value, this loop will *fire* 0 or 2 times, but never 1 time only.

Answer (score 0):

This may be closer to what you are trying:

```
FOR i = 1 TO 2
    input1(i) = input1(i) * weight1(i)
    input2(i) = input2(i) * weight2(i)
NEXT i
FOR i = 1 TO 2
    sum(i) = input1(i) + input2(i)
NEXT i
FOR i = 1 TO 2
    IF sum(i) > 0 THEN CALL fire
NEXT i
END
```